# Memory limit for class object we can have in azure hosted web api?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

We have web api hosted on azure in net framework 461 as target framework and libraries of .net core 2.1.

We are actually calling a 3rd party api and getting data in GBs, and again we need to process this data.

Is there any object memory limitations?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the underlying app service plan. You are limited to 1024 MB for the Free and Shared plans. The higher plans are limited by the VM's they run on, you can use the [pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/calculator/?service=app-service) to investigate the instance size. Keep in mind there will be some overhead on the VM's so you will likely only be able to leverage roughly ~75% of the capacity reliably. Please find the Azure App Service plan limits [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits).

You should also consider you application design carefully, can you implement your client with streaming the data received from the API and processing it as it "passes through" This way you can you process huge files without running in to memory limitations. I googled around and found an example of what I am talking about [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1180464/Large-JSON-Array-Streaming-in-ASP-NET-Web-API).